# Delete Record and its attachment Trigger is not working

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

```
trigger MyDocumentTgr on MyDocument__c (after delete) {
    private List<MyDocument__c> mdObjLst {get; set;}
    private List<Attachment> attObjLst {get; set;}
    set<ID> mdId = new set<ID>();
    Set<string> attId = new set<string>();

    for(MyDocument__c md : Trigger.Old){
        mdId.add(md.Id);
    }

    mdObjLst = [Select id,name,Uploaded_File__c from MyDocument__c Where Id IN : mdId];  

    for(MyDocument__c md : mdObjLst){
        attId.add(md.Uploaded_File__c);
    }

    attObjLst = [Select id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :attId];
    System.debug('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'+attObjLst);
    if(!attObjLst.isEmpty()){
        delete attObjLst;
    }  
}
    mdObjLst = [Select id,name,Account__c from MyDocument__c Where Id IN : mdId];    
    attObj = [Select id,ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE Id =:mdObj.Uploaded_File__c AND ParentId =:mdObj.Account__c];
    if(!mdObjLst.isEmpty()){
        delete mdObjLst;
        delete attObj;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Getting null pointer exception in attObj..

Comment: mdObj.Uploaded_File__c has the single corresponding attachment id..

Comment: Where did you initialise `mdObj`

Comment: @TusharSharma..i updated the trigger

Comment: Get,set on a trigger? Not sure you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked this, but think you can eliminate the two queries and quite a lot of lines like this:

```
trigger MyDocumentTgr on MyDocument__c (before delete) {
    Map<Id, Attachment> atts = new Map<Id, Attachment>();
    for (MyDocument__c md : Trigger.old) {
        Id attId = md.Uploaded_File__c;
        if (attId != null) {
            atts.put(attId, new Attachment(Id = attId));
        }
    }
    delete atts.values();
}
```

This takes advantage of all the fields of the object the trigger is firing on being available without requerying and that when you have the Id of an object there is no need to query an instance before you update or delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger MyDocumentTgr on MyDocument__c (before delete) {
    private List<MyDocument__c> mdObjLst = new List<MyDocument__c>();
    private List<Attachment> attObjLst = new List<Attachment>();
    set<ID> mdId = new set<ID>();
    Set<string> attId = new set<string>();

    for(MyDocument__c md : Trigger.Old){
        mdId.add(md.Id);
    }

    mdObjLst = [Select id,name,Uploaded_File__c from MyDocument__c Where Id IN : mdId];  

    for(MyDocument__c md : mdObjLst){
        attId.add(md.Uploaded_File__c);
    }

    attObjLst = [Select id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :attId];
    if(!attObjLst.isEmpty()){
        delete attObjLst;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Instead of declaring the variables at the start of a method you can declare them where you assign the real value e.g. `List<MyDocument__c> mdObjLst = [Select id,name...];`. That reduces the possibility of referencing the variable where it is set to an invalid value: the variable is either out of scope or set to a valid value and never null or set to an invalid empty list.

Comment: @KeithC..you are genius..